# Defining constant function on open set seemingly leads to contradiction in definitions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

If we define a function $f:I\to \{c\}$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$ by $x \mapsto c$, I seem to get to a contradiction in definitions.

On the one hand $f$ is continuous but on the other hand the preimage $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ of the closed set $\{c\}$ containing only the single point $c$ is the open set $I$. But we know that any function is continuous if and only if the preimage of any closed set is closed.

Is there any flaw I did not catch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151178/discussion-between-soham-saha-and-xander-henderson).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a topology on a set to be a way of choosing which sets are open, and as a consequence which sets are closed. There are some axioms that the open sets have to satisfy, but you can look those up, and I don't think they are so necessary for a basic understanding of the following discussion.

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $U\subset X$ a subset of $X$ (open, closed, neither, both it doesn't matter). Then the subspace topology on $U$ is the more or less "correct" way of deciding which subsets of $U$ are open inside of $U$. It is  defined by saying $V\subset U$ is open (res. closed) if and only if there exists a $Y\subset X$ which is open in $X$ (res. closed) such that $V=Y\cap U$.

Now, in the subspace topology, it clear that $U$ is both open and closed, as it should be. Indeed, $X$ is both open and closed in $X$, and $U\cap X=U$.

Now if $X$ is $\textit{any}$ topological space, and $U\subset X$ is $\textit{any}$ subset endowed with the subspace topology we have that the constant function $U\rightarrow \{c\}$ is continuous. Indeed, there is only one topology on the singleton set, the one where $\{c\}$ is both open and closed. We clearly have that $f^{-1}(c)=U$, and as mentioned, in the subspace topology, $U$ is both open and closed, so $f$ is continuous.

It's important to note that we can't talk about what continuity means on random sets, they need to be endowed with a topology. So, when you're dealing with a function restricted to some subset of a topological space, you usually put the subspace topology on it, as that kind of the only thing you can do most of the time.